# conda env fails to create new environment

Tags: python, conda

When trying to create a new environment of the tool viper, I get stuck while solving package specifications.

I have downloaded the tool from their [website](https://bitbucket.org/cfce/viper/src/master/) and unpacked it. Following the instructions I'm trying to create a conda environment named viper.

Using the command

```
conda env create -f environment.yml -n viper
```

the process got stuck as mentioned above. 
So I tried

```
conda create --file environment.yml -n viper
```

but I get the error

```
CondaValueError: could not parse 'name: viper' in: environment.yml
```

the header of my environment.yml file is attached below

```
 name: viper
 channels: #!!python/tuple
     - bioconda
     - conda-forge
     - defaults
 dependencies:
     - ...
```

What do I do wrong?

THe conda version I have is as such:

```
 $ conda info
 Current conda install:

           platform : linux-64
      conda version : 4.3.30
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.30
conda-build version : not installed
     python version : 3.6.3.final.0
   requests version : 2.18.4
   root environment : /home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3  (writable)
default environment : /home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3
   envs directories : /home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3/envs
                      /home/yeroslaviz/.conda/envs
      package cache : /home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3/pkgs
                      /home/yeroslaviz/.conda/pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
        config file : None
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
         user-agent : conda/4.3.30 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.3 Linux/4.4.0-72-generic debian/stretch/sid glibc/2.23    
            UID:GID : 1000:1000
```

thanks

Comment: I'm looking at that tool's [environment.yml](https://bitbucket.org/cfce/viper/src/master/envs/environment.yml) and it is extremely underspecified, i.e., many packages lack explicit versions and major hub software (e.g., Python and R) only have lower bounds. I would kindly ask the author to send you a YAML that includes versions on everything. Otherwise, combined with the fact that this is from circa 2016, I think the search space is problematically large.

Comment: you can do `conda env create --file environment.yml -n myenv python=3.8` (btw you can create the env with `conda env export > environment.yml` it adds the pip dependencies automatically too)

Comment: This is already closed, but thanks

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`conda create --file environment.yml -n viper` won't work. This command tries to parse every line in the `environment.yml` as a package name.

You should use `conda env create --file environment.yml -n viper`.

Just wait patiently for the conflict resolution to be done.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have waited and alas it did come :-)

Comment: don't forget to specify the python version e.g. `conda env create --file environment.yml -n myenv python=3.8` (fyi you can create the env with `conda env export > environment.yml` it adds the pip dependencies automatically too)

Comment: whose bright idea was it to have a YAML format for `conda env` but not for `conda create`?

Comment: @user5339351,  I think that was Jo.

Comment: Just a small comment to dissuade using `conda env export > environment.yml` as this creates an enormous environment.yml that typically is not portable between systems. Usually `conda env export --from-history > environment.yml` is better. Using mamda instead of conda is better still.